# Where can I download a ca.pem file for boost::asio::ssl?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

In the example of [doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp - 1.58.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp), it loads a file named `ca.pem`, but where can I download it? I've tried to export one from Firefox, and also tried to use the one in my system such as `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt`, but the example program only returns message

```
Verifying /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Handshake failed: certificate verify failed
```

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You never actually told us what you want to achieve. You just asked "Where can I download a ca.pem" - apparently you needed +a specific authority+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Mozilla certificate pack converted to PEM format by the authors of cURL library. You can download it from [cURL site](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

I tried to run this boost.asio example using this pack and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the library source tree:

```
libs/asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.pem
libs/asio/example/cpp03/ssl/dh512.pem
libs/asio/example/cpp03/ssl/ca.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found it and tried it yesterday, and still got the same failure. The command line I used is `./a.out www.google.com https`. Maybe the ca.pem file can only be used to check the connection with the demo server. I know little about OpenSSL. Maybe I shall learn OpenSSL first.

Comment: Yes, it is totally a demo file.

Comment: @Cody you should use a certificate signed by a trusted CA (certificate authority) or otherwise the verification will reflect that the certificate is not trusted. You can _buy_ certificates (requiring some paperwork to apply for the trust) or you can generate certificates yourself and/or add the issuer (the signing CA) to your own list of trusted CAs.

Comment: You might find a search on [SU] informative ([e.g.](http://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=trusted%20certificate)) or just head to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure)