# Creating a HTTPS request using Boost Asio and OpenSSL

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have created a simple HTTP request wherein I am sending GET,POST and PUT requests to the server. Next I want to switch to HTTPS connection using boost asio library, how should I proceed?

I have an Executor Class that resolves and connects to the server and a RequestCreator Class that creates the request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I happen to just have posted such a thing in a comment (...):

> [You just connect over ssl. @Milind coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9546326fd1def416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761058/how-to-send-http-request-and-retrieve-a-json-response-c-boost/26761889#comment67360963_26761889)

So perhaps it is helpful to you.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9546326fd1def416)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    using namespace boost::asio;

    // what we need
    io_service svc;
    ssl::context ctx(svc, ssl::context::method::sslv23_client);
    ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket> ssock(svc, ctx);
    ssock.lowest_layer().connect({ {}, 8087 }); // http://localhost:8087 for test
    ssock.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);

    // send request
    std::string request("GET /newGame?name=david HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
    boost::asio::write(ssock, buffer(request));

    // read response
    std::string response;

    do {
        char buf[1024];
        size_t bytes_transferred = ssock.read_some(buffer(buf), ec);
        if (!ec) response.append(buf, buf + bytes_transferred);
    } while (!ec);

    // print and exit
    std::cout << "Response received: '" << response << "'\n";
}
```

To emulate a server for demo purposes I've been using the certificate and params from the Asio samples (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201907/85371).

**UPDATE** Here's a version that uses resolver to resolve the endpoint (Coliru doesn't allow us to do that, but it does work on non-restricted machines).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53d2757a5d3eb00f)</kbd>**

```
ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
auto it = resolver.resolve({"localhost", "8087"}); // http://localhost:8087 for test
boost::asio::connect(ssock.lowest_layer(), it);

// and the rest unaltered
ssock.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);
```

Comment: This dosen't seem to work as i am using resolver and not endpoint   tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
     tcp::resolver::query query(cli.getIP(), "8080");

Comment: Don't give link to boost website or github sample code, i have tried all of those(almost all)

Comment: Do you have any custom code that just makes a connection using resolver @sehe

Comment: @DevMac Found the time to answer your comment, see the UPDATE. What online samples have you found that were more confusing than this?

Comment: You have used auto here which is compiler dependent, right ?

Comment: and how do you gracefully close the connection/socket if any error arises ? @sehe

Comment: `auto` is not compiler dependent. It's standards version dependent in the sense that c++11 introduced it. All compilers support it in c++11 mode. What do you mean by graceful close? Perhaps it is time to search for existing answers to your different questions. If all else fails, you can ask a new question

Comment: I am basically taking the result of resolver.resolve(query) in   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator

Comment: I just suggested what I think you should do. The comment thread is not well suited as a personal support forum. Also, by reusing/posting questions on the main site you (a) make it possible for many more people to help (b) make it possible for many more people to find your solutions

Answer (score 0):

> Simple example:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>

using namespace boost::beast;
using namespace boost::asio;

using std::string;
using std::cout;


int
main() {

    const string host = "www.google.com";
    const string path = "/";
    const string port = "443";

    io_service svc;

    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23_client);
    ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket> ssocket = { svc, ctx };
    ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
    auto it = resolver.resolve(host, port);
    connect(ssocket.lowest_layer(), it);
    ssocket.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);
    http::request<http::string_body> req{ http::verb::get, path, 11 };
    req.set(http::field::host, host);
    http::write(ssocket, req);
    http::response<http::string_body> res;
    flat_buffer buffer;
    http::read(ssocket, buffer, res);
    cout << "Headers" << std::endl;
    cout << res.base() << std::endl << std::endl;
    cout << "Body" << std::endl;
    cout << res.body() << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```